# Is it possible to "chain" Laravel RESTful routing?

Tags: php, laravel, web-frameworks

I understand with Laravel you can use `Route::resource` route methods to handle things like `/user/1` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

What I was wondering is how to create the best way to "chain" methods so I am not repeating code.

For example say I have `/team/1/user/1`, I could route this a `TeamUsers` controller which grabs the team and the user from the database in the "show" method.

Now if I wanted to create a `/team/1/group/1` route to a `TeamGroups` controller, I would have duplicate code to grab the team again from the database.

What would be the best way to chain backwards and only write the retrieving team code at one point?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Laravel actually has a concept of [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) which takes care of this for you. So your code would end up looking something like:

```
Route::get('team/{team}/user/{user}', function (App\Team $team, App\User $user) {
    $team_name = $team->name;
    $user_name = $user->name;
});
```

And then the same for the group:

```
Route::get('team/{team}/group/{group}', function (App\Team $team, App\Group $group) {
    $team_name = $team->name;
    $group_name = $group->name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested resource https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Nested Resources
Sometimes you may need to define routes to a "nested" resource. For example, a photo resource may have multiple "comments" that may be attached to the photo. To "nest" resource controllers, use "dot" notation in your route declaration:

`Route::resource('photos.comments', 'PhotoCommentController');`

This route will register a "nested" resource that may be accessed with URLs like the following:  `photos/{photos}/comments/{comments}`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PhotoCommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the specified photo comment.
     *
     * @param  int  $photoId
     * @param  int  $commentId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($photoId, $commentId)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write Repository class where you can grab all data, for example
https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/